# Javascript check function exists if made up of two strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am playing around with the Garber-Irish implementation (using typescript) and I have the following Typescript code where I want to check if the type of `controller + "Controller"` is valid function.

If I uncomment the comment then `typeof(controller + "Controller")` is always a string (to be expected).

If I comment the code and run this if then `new window[controller + "Controller"]` returns an error if the window does not have a valid function for example  `fooController`

```
var util = {
    exec: function (controller: string, action: string) {
        //if (typeof(controller + "Controller") !== 'function') return;

        var ctrlClass = new window[controller + "Controller"];
        if (ctrlClass === undefined) return; //this is most likely redundant

        if (action === undefined)
            ctrlClass.init();
        else {
            if (ctrlClass[action] && typeof ctrlClass[action] == "function") {
                ctrlClass[action]();
            }
        }
    },

    init: function () {
        var body = document.body,
            controller = $("body").data("controller").toLowerCase(),
            action = $("body").data("action").toLowerCase();

        GlobalApp.common.init();
        util.exec(controller);
        util.exec(controller, action);
    }
};
```

So my question is how do I go about to check if a function exists if it is made up of two strings e.g. "home" + "controller".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
typeof window[controller+"Controller"] === "function"
```

Comment: I thought I tried that but noticed I tried `typeof(new( window[controller+"Controller"])` I forgot to remove the new! Your version seems to work fine. thanks

Comment: no problem.  easy to miss stuff when you're trying a bunch of different combinations.

Comment: yep, functional languages :)

Answer (score 0):

use typeof, show my code:

```js
class Manage{
  public test(data: any){
    console.log(data)
  }
}

let manage = new Manage();

for(let i in manage){
  if(typeof (manage as any)[i] === 'function'){
    console.log('function')
  }
  else{
    console.log(typeof i) 
  }
}
```